# Can there be more than one struct member per line?

Tags: vlang

Can I have more than one `struct` member per line?

I was making a struct. It seems like V enforces only one member per line.
I don't recall seeing that mentioned anywhere.

```
trial.v:191:2: error: unknown type `` 
  189 |     fsize    int
  190 |     vers     int
  191 |     x,y,z    i16
      |     ~~
  192 |     c    int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you cannot use the comma shortcut in field declarations. For example, the following works:

```
struct S { x int y int z f32 }

fn main() {
    s := S { x: 10 y: 20 z: 3.14 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah, cannot use comma for the declaration of the struct, but it is ok to use for the initialization:

```
struct Xyz { x int y int z f32 }
fn main() {
    s := Xyz{ x: 11, y: 20, z: 3.14 }
    println(s.x)
}
```

Btw, name of a struct in V needs to start in uppercase and be at least 3 characters long.